# Java Area.intersects(Rectangle) out of bounds

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

im pretty new to programming so this might be really obvious, but when i run this part of my code

```
public void movePlayer(){
    Rectangle playerRect = new Rectangle((int) player.getxPositie(),(int) player.getyPositie()-12,20,35);

    if(water.intersects(playerRect)){//out of bounds????
        player.swim=true;
        jump=true;
        if(SplashP == true){
                SplashP=false;
                Splash((int) (player.getxPositie()/5),versnelling*12);
        }else{}

    }else{  player.swim=false;
            SplashP = true;}
        }
...
```

i get the following Exception and i don't know why

```
Exception in thread "Thread-20" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0
    at java.util.Vector.get(Vector.java:748)
    at java.awt.geom.Area.getCachedBounds(Area.java:434)
    at java.awt.geom.Area.intersects(Area.java:606)
    at java.awt.geom.Area.intersects(Area.java:618)
    at Model.movePlayer(Model.java:723)
    at Animator.run(Animator.java:19)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Another strange thing is that when the water intersects the player the else case alse gets triggerd half of the time

PS. Area water is build from a collection of triangles

Comment: do you change `water` in another thread at the same time?

Comment: So why don' t you check if you really do have this amount of elements in array ?

Comment: @Asakura because it is an internal member in `java.awt.geom.Area`

Comment: not realy sure how threads work(cause i have one thread where i call all my methods from but i still have multiple threads), but when i run game now the exeption  says "Thread-1". so i think yes

Comment: do you get this exception every time you run this part of the code or only occasionally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at `java.awt.geom.Area.getCachedBounds` line 433-434 (see your stacktrace) then you find

```
private Rectangle2D getCachedBounds() {
    ...
    if (curves.size() > 0) {                 // 433
        Curve c = (Curve) curves.get(0);     // 434
```

`curves` is a member of `Area` of type `Vector`. 
The code checks if `curves` is **not empty** and then accesses the first element.
This then raises an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` which can only happen when `curves` **is** empty.

So there must be another thread which modifies the `water` object in between.

Comment: i reset my area water after i added all the triangles. I think thats the problem

Comment: @cockadoodledoo probably. When resetted the area sets `curves` to a new empty Vector.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this intersects function does not allow for Rect input. I also advice you to make sure your code is in one language. I happen to know what your variables do because I am Dutch myself, but for the sake of consistency as well as everyone being able to read your code I advice you to make everything in English.

Comment: in javadoc it says intersection(Rectangle) r)https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html